# NumberFormatException for input string with comma in DecimalFormat

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm encountering a java.lang.NumberFormatException in my Android app with Kotlin and Java when using the following code:

```
fun roundOffDecimal(number: Float): Float {
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.#")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.FLOOR
    return df.format(number).toFloat()
}
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException
For input string: "0,3"
```

I'm puzzled by this error because the function parameter is a Float, and there should be no possibility of receiving input values with a comma. Here are some observations and considerations:

- This issue seems to be specific to a particular user as it is working as expected for others.
- The error occurs when calling df.format(number), which returns a string. This makes me suspect that there might be a localization issue or something related to the user's locale settings.
- The user who reported this issue is from South Africa, which raises the question of whether there could be a country-specific issue related to number formatting or locale settings.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and understand why it's occurring for this specific user while working for others. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _there should be no possibility of receiving input values with a comma._ Are you not aware that different countries have different [decimal separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator)? By the way, thousands separator also varies by country.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use method [floor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) (of class `java.lang.Math`) rather than converting a float to a string and then back to a float?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: I do not know Kotlin, but in Java, `DecimalFormat.format()` will return a `String` and is `Locale`-sensitive, that is, if the default `Locale` is set to use a comma, it will return a `String` with a comma! I suspect that `toFloat()` is the equivalent to `Float.parseFloat()` in Java, which is **not** `Locale`-sensitive, so you are getting an error since the first method returned a comma. (hardy an Android bug that the error message states `"0,3"`  with a comma and there is none)

Comment: BTW also be warned that `float` and `double` (in Java) are not able to correctly represent all numbers and they do no have a *number of decimal digits* (e.g. `0.3` is more like `0.300000011920928955078125`; it is the `toString` method that does not show all decimal digits)

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
val df = DecimalFormat("#.#")
```

into this:

```
val df = DecimalFormat("#.#", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))
```

With this change, regardless of the user's locale settings, your method will always format and parse numbers using a period as the decimal separator. This should prevent the `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.